# Create a REST API scaling SQL Server

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I want to create a REST API which scales the maximum size of my Azure SQL Server Database and include that API in my Azure Function

I tried by the normal requests like PUT,PATCH but everytime it shows that Authorization Header is missing. How to include the Authorization header in the Request part??

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not  must to use REST API to scale the Azure SQL database, you can refenence this document: [Scale your Azure SQL Database with Azure Functions](https://wp.sjkp.dk/scale-your-azure-sql-database-with-azure-functions/):

To automatically scale the database up from Azure Functions, using the following code:

```
private static async Task ScaleDatabaseUp()
{
            var constring = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQL_DB");
            var query = string.Format(@"
ALTER DATABASE <DATABASENAME>
    MODIFY (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'PRS1'); --PRS1");
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            }           
}
```

You have to replace  with the name of your database and potentially also the service objective (SKU).

Hope this helps.

Comment: For me it is must using REST API. I got the output in this SQL Method. Thank you for helping out. If you get any methods using REST API please do respond